# How to paginate table in laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm still new to laravel. I'm trying to include a paginate function here in my app and I find the paginate function of laravel a bit confusing. Can Somebody help me with this? Here's my code:

*usertable.blade.php*

```
<div class="container-fluid col-xs-7 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Update Records </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Username</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Department</th>               
                                    <th>Action</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                @foreach($records as $key=>$record)
                                 <tr>
                                     <td class="col-xs-2">{{$record->name}}</td>
                                     <td class="col-xs-6">{{$record->wholename}} @if($record->isBACSec == 1)<strong>-BAC Secretariat</strong>@endif</td>
                                     <td class="col-xs-2">{{$record->department}}</td>
                                     <td class="col-xs-2"><a class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" href="{{ URL::to('edit/'.$record->id) }}">Edit</a>
                                     <a class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" href="{{ URL::to('delete/'.$record->id) }}" onclick="return confirm('WARNING.'+'\n'+'DELETING USER RECORDS. Continue?');">Delete</a></td>


                                     </td> 
                                 </tr>
                                @endforeach

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    {{ $records->links() }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

*RecordsController.php*

```
public function edit($id)
    {
        //find record of given id
        $edit_form = User::find($id);
        $records = User::all()->paginate(15);
        $dept = Office::all();
        $result = DB::table('users')
                ->where('isBACSec', '=', 1)
                ->get();

        //show edit form and pass the info to it
        return View('updateuser')
        ->with('edit_form',$edit_form)
        ->with('dept',$dept)
        ->with('records',$records)
        ->with('result',$result);

    }
```

Comment: You can use database level pagination, see: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination. (in SQL we use OFFSET LIMIT to achieve this: https://www.guru99.com/limit.html)

Comment: Thank you for your insight! @AbhinavSaxena

Comment: It will be my pleasure, if the article gives some help.

Comment: Here is one more: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-offset-fetch-clause/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the docs over [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination)

You can simply append the `paginate()` function to your query. 
As an argument you pass the desired pagination length. F.e. if you want 15 results returned `paginate(15)`.

```
//find record of given id
$edit_form = User::find($id);
$records = User::all()->paginate(15);
$dept = Office::all();
$result = DB::table('users')
          ->where('isBACSec', '=', 1)
          ->paginate(15) // Changes here
```

Comment: Method links does not exist. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ein\IPPS\resources\views\usertable.blade.php) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\ein\IPPS\resources\views\usertable.blade.php)

Comment: I think it might be this {{ $records->links() }}? Bit confused.

Comment: The error you are mentioning is not refered to the pagination. If you want to `egger load` another model in your query you need to define a `with` statement. In your template file remove `$records->links()` to see if it is working in general

Comment: Thank you! It works now. changed this $records = User::all()->paginate(15); to this: $records = DB::table('users')->paginate(15); @Traxstar